# How to design Custom Tab in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` components. I am using `tabs` in my project. I am also using `styled components` also. I have used `tabs` which looks like this
[image]

But My Requirement was this
[image]

When the tab is selected, i need only a line in below of it. And other tab names should be in grey color. I searched but can't find proper solutions. Please help me with some solutions.

Here's the Code I tried:

```
import Tab from "react-bootstrap/Tab";
import Tabs from "react-bootstrap/Tabs";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

export default function App() {
  const CustomTabs = styled(Tabs)`
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray;
    color: white;
  `;
  const CustomTab = styled(Tab)`
    color: gray;
    font-size: 19px;

    :active {
      color: black;
      border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomTabs defaultActiveKey="tab1" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
        <CustomTab eventKey="tab1" title="Tab1">
          Tab1 Content
        </CustomTab>
        <CustomTab eventKey="tab2" title="Tab2">
          Tab2 Content
        </CustomTab>
        <CustomTab eventKey="tab3" title="Tab3">
          Tab3 Content
        </CustomTab>
      </CustomTabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have found these css. But I don't how to use it in styled components. Anyone help me with this

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: orangered;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: none;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover{
    color: color:gray
}
```

Comment: You can inspect the element in the browser, and find the classes which are applying the currently applied default style, and then use that exact classes and apply your css to them.

Comment: @Arrow, I inspected that. It showing `nav link` class name. But I don't know how to use it in styled components

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't want apply styled-components directly to the react-bootstrap components, but what you can do is create an element to wrap the react-bootstrap components and use the CSS classes you get from inspecting to make it work.

```
const StyledWrap = styled.div`
  & .nav-tabs li {
    background-color: red;
  }

  & .nav-tabs .active li {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`
const CustomNavbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <StyledWrap>
        <NavItem active={true} />
        <NavItem />
    </StyledWrap>
  )
}
```